# Create my own custom keyboard with my own images / emoticons

Tags: ios, uitextview, uikeyboard

I would like to create a custom keyboard with my own images and layout, similar to the app "Emotikarl" on the AppStore.

Please take a look at this screenshot:

[image: custom keyboard example]

I would like to add my own list of images / emoticons (all the images will be created by me) to the keyboard. And when I tap an image / emoticon, the image / emoticon will be inserted in the text view at the top of the app.

I already tried looking on Github and other websites, but I didn't find anything like this. How should I do this?

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Answer (score 2):

You need implement your custom keyboard as subclass of UIView, implement all UI, actions.

Also you need custom UIView for toolbar with selector between keyboards.
(by changing UITextField's inputView property to your custom keyboard, or to nil, for standard keyboard)
Then you can set UITextField's inputAccessoryView to this custom toolbar.

Check attached custom keyboard from one of my projects:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48223929/CustomizeTextFieldKeyboard.zip

[image]